# question regarding UIDeviceRGB

Tags: iphone

*** -[UIDeviceRGBColor size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3467e0

I don't know what to do for this error
plz tell me how to resolve this exception
I even do not understand the meaning of UIDeviceRGBColour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that object you send message to has been deallocated and another object occupies its location in memory. Run your application in debug mode and look at exact line in stack where crash happens in your code - you must have problems with memory management for some object at that line.